# Printing a table somewhat complex MYSQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with 2 tables User, Contact_List.

The User table for example looks like this:

```
  U_id | U_email | U_password | U_mobileNo | U_name |
  ---------------------------------------------------
  1    | a@b.c   | aaa        | 1234567    | Adam   |

  2    | b@b.c   | bbb        | 1234567    | Ben    |

  3    | c@b.c   | ccc        | 1234567    | Carl   |
```

The Contact_list table looks like this. This table is table just consisting of foreign keys that relate two users together

```
  U_id | U_contact_id
  -------------------
  1    |     2

  2    |     3
```

Now the problem is my SQL/PHP query to display a table that consists of a specific users list of contacts.

This SQL query works fine and gives the results I want:

```
"SELECT cu.u_name, cu.u_email 
FROM contact_list = c, user = u, user = cu
WHERE c.u_id = 2 
AND c.u_contactId = c.u_id
AND c.u_id = u.u_id"
```

But this PHP code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("dbname","dbuser","pbpass","db");
//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cu.u_name, cu.u_email 
  FROM contact_list = c, user = u, user = cu
  WHERE c.u_id = 2 
  AND c.u_contactId = c.u_id
  AND c.u_id = u.u_id" ) or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<table border='1'>
 <th>Contact List</th>
 <tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>E-mail</th>
 </tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['u_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['u_email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";


 }
  echo "</table>";  
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

That code just prints a blank table on the page.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am a complete noob using PHP any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: for  a start move mysqli_free_result outside the loop

Comment: try replacing `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`

Comment: @Sonali that is not the issue....if it was then `AND c.u_id = >u.u_id"` this line produce error....isn't it.?

Comment: changed the SQL query (that was a typo on my behalf), moved the mysqli_free_result outside the loop, lol that wasn;t supposed to be there.

Comment: replacing to mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) didnt do much it seems, same results

Comment: @user2716766 what is your desired result from those 2 tables? You have more problems than you think u do, your query is completely messed up as it is and is extremely ambiguous so its only normal to get no result.

Comment: @Prix well the idea is for a user to be to store multiple contacts in this system I am working on. The goal of the query is to get details from that contact related to the user (am I making sense?)

Comment: @user2716766 Assuming that the contact list table will not have a user having himself as his contact, This condition(c.u_contactId = c.u_id) in your query  will never be true...right? You you will not get any rows from your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to retrieve all the contacts of user with id 2 so basically your query would look like this:

```
SELECT u.u_name, u.u_email 
  FROM contact_list cl
  JOIN user u
    ON cl.u_contact_id = u.u_id
 WHERE cl.u_id = 2
```

[**Live DEMO.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c88b7/1/0)

What the above query does is, it will join the users information based on the `u_contact_id` and will list all the names and emails registered to it.

And your PHP would look like this:

```
<?php
// your database info here
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
if($con->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

if (!$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT u.u_name, u.u_email 
                             FROM contact_list cl
                             JOIN user u
                               ON cl.u_contact_id = u.u_id
                            WHERE cl.u_id = ?"))
    die('Prepare Error: ' . $con->error);

$id = 2;
if (!$stmt->bind_param('i', $id))
    die('Bind Parameters Error ' . $stmt->error);

if (!$stmt->execute())
    die('Select Query Error ' . $stmt->error);
?>
<table border="1">
 <th>Contact List</th>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>E-mail</th>
 </tr>
<?php
$stmt->bind_result($name,$email);
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
echo "</table>";
$stmt->close();
$con->close();
```

Comment: your SQL statement does make a lot more sense to me but now for some unknown reason the the table does not appear at all now, where a table with blank fields was shown before. Don't know how changing an SQl statement could do that, something wrong with my PHP code?

Comment: @user2716766 see the demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c88b7/1/0 the query I am using will JOIN the information from users based on the u_contact_id's field to find the name and emails a given user have.

Comment: @user2716766 Actually this query from Prix makes more sense and is correct. Also see my comment above as your query will always return zero rows assuming contact list does not store a user as his own contact, so c.u_contactId = c.u_id condition will always be false

Comment: @rakeshjain that's exactly why I said his query was ambiguous on the comments there ;) he is doing or trying to do some weird FROM mix that makes no sense with too many compares on the WHERE making it unable to work.

Comment: @user2716766 don't forget to use prepared statements like I have on my sample code above so you don't get vulnerable to SQL Injection ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a var_dump on $row, you may find out more on what went wrong, if no var_dump appears, no result return  was  returned, use  mysqli_error to find out what went wrong

```
 mysqli_error($con);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
     var_dump($row);
 }
```

It could be a case issue

```
$row['u_name']
```

may be is

```
$row['U_name']
```

Comment: var_dump shows nothing... honestly did not know that case they were case sensitive, but still changed them and still have no results in my table

Comment: could you try a simple query (SELECT * FROM User) see if you get any results? if not it may be a DB connection issue on your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cu.u_name, cu.u_email 
FROM contact_list c, user u, user cu
WHERE c.u_id = 2 
AND c.u_contactId = c.u_id
AND c.u_id = u.u_id
```

Maybe it's just that I suffer insomnia, but that should work

Answer (score 0):

In your query:

1. Your syntax for specifying table alias is wrong. There is no need for the `=` sign.
2. You are aliasing `user` as both `u` and `cu`, but seems like you can get by with just one.

Try the following:

```
SELECT cu.u_name, cu.u_email 
FROM contact_list c, user u     // Or alternatively: FROM contact_list AS c, user AS u
WHERE c.u_id = 2 
AND c.u_contactId = c.u_id
AND c.u_id = u.u_id
```

By the way, when printing the `<table>`, you need to place `<th>` inside `<tr>` for valid HTML.

Also, in your `$result = mysql_query (....)` you ended it with `or die (mysql_error())`. It should be `or die (mysqli_error())`.